# how to download 1000 images from google image search

Tags: java, image, search-engine, search-engine-api

is there anyone know how to download top 1000 images from google image search?
I tried google ajax api but it return only 65 images :(
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can't you just make HttpRequests for each page (just change the start for each HttpRequest).
http://www.google.com/images?q=test&start=10

Then search all <img> tags and download the source.

Comment: See this:- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11876/An-API-for-Google-Image-Search

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can I draw your attention to this paragraph of the Google Terms of Service:

> 5.3 You agree not to access (or attempt to access) any of the Services by any means other than through the interface that is provided by Google, unless you have been specifically allowed to do so in a separate agreement with Google. You specifically agree not to access (or attempt to access) any of the Services through any automated means (including use of scripts or web crawlers) and shall ensure that you comply with the instructions set out in any robots.txt file present on the Services.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) which could be useful with some shell scriptin.

[php cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) could be useful too in case you are more familiar with PHP.

Most languages have some mechanism to make http requests, receive and parse the HTML responses and download the images you want to download.

Answer (score 0):

I would use WGET to pickup only GIF/JPG and just do it manually through SSH, unless you want this to happen through PHP, not sure why.